# How to make Sails.js app listen to events of ethereum blokchain to perform CRUD on persistence layer

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ethereum, web3js

I have a smart contract deployed on Ethereum blockchain and it emits some event with necessary data.

I have a sails.js application which needs to listen to this event.

Roughly, the JavaScript code looks like:

```js
var event = contract.myEvent();
event.watch((err, res) => {
    console.log(res); // event response
    // API call to DB for persistence
});
```

Where should this code sit in sails.js application as sails.js follows MVC, is it a good idea to use sails.js?

Answer (score 0):

This code should be excuted as a Service at the application start time.

for example you can create a file named EventsService.js :

```
let event = contract.myEvent();

exports.start = function () {

  event.watch((err, res) => {
    console.log(res); // event response
    // API call to DB for persistence
});
}
```

and then you can start the service like this: (from the app.js file)

```
const eventService = require('path/to/EventService.js');

eventService.start();
```